# bind reactive form formControlName in ng2-select2 directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Reactive Form for handling form in my `Angular 5` project. And in that form I'm using `ng2-select2` to create my select2 dropdown, but when I'm trying to bind `formControlName` into my `<select2></select2>` directive, it gives me error

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'citizenship_id'

Here is my ngOnInit function in .ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.jobId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.jobId;
    this.detailForm = new FormGroup({
        date_of_birth: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        marital_status: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        npwp_family_status_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        citizenship_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });

    this.ajaxOptions = {
        url: API_URL + '/generate-json',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                s: params.term,
                page: params.page,
                model_name: 'country'
            };
        },
        type: 'POST',
        processResults: function (res) {
            let data = $.map(res.results, function (obj) {
                if (obj.overwriteId)
                    obj.id = obj.overwriteId;
                return obj;
            });

            return {
                results: data,
                pagination: res.pagination
            };
        }
    };

    this.options = {
        ajax: this.ajaxOptions,
        // theme: 'bootstrap',
        width: '100%',
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Select...',
        language: {
            'errorLoading': function () {
                return 'Searching…';
            }
        },
        templateResult: function (data) {
            return data.create === true ? data.text + ' <b style="color: lightgreen;">(create new)</b>' : data.text;
        },
        templateSelection: function (data) {
            return data.create === true ? data.text + ' <b class="text-success">(create new)</b>' : data.text;
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        },
        createTag: function (params) {
            var term = $.trim(params.term);
            return term ? {
                id: term,
                text: term,
                create: true
            } : null;
        },
        insertTag: function (data, tag) {
            var found = false;
            $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                if (e.text.toLowerCase() == tag.text.toLowerCase())
                    found = true;
            });
            if (!found)
                data.unshift(tag);
        },
        minimumInputLength: 2
    };
}
```

And this is my .html file:

```
<select2 [options]="options" formControlName="citizenship_id"></select2>
```

Comment: Did you define `<form [detailForm]="form">` in your html ?

Comment: @SunilSingh I do define it `<form class="" id="personal-details-form" [formGroup]="detailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">`. The problem is, I can get the other inputs but this select2 input.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @DennyRustandi?

Comment: @Asif I create a new hidden input that binded to formControlName. and whenever I change the value of the select2 I update the value of the hidden input as well

Comment: @DennyRustandi but the problem is how can i show the selected value to users?

Comment: @Asif Like you get the response from API and you want to pre-select the value? In my case, I have an array variable that contained with my selected value from the response ex: `[{id: 1, text: 'Selected Value'}]` and then in select2 directive I set `[value]="{selected_value_id}"`

Comment: Hi @DennyRustandi, and All, Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Select2 doesn't work with ReactiveForms natively, here's a good workaround solution:

Create a new hidden input bound to formControlName. Whenever value of select2 is changed, update the value of the hidden input as well.

If you get the response from API and you want to pre-select the value, Use an array variable with selected value from the response (e.g.: `[{id: 1, text: 'Selected Value'}]` then in select2 directive, set `[value]="{selected_value_id}"`).

Credit to OP @DennyRustandi and @SunilSingh for this info in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your custom component `select2`. It seems your component is not implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. Just ensure your component does implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

See the simple example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-from-control-hqpwgb

Refer this nice article - https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

Comment: So is it fair to say then that ng2-select2 will not be work with reactiveForm functionality until the developers implement `ControlValueAccessor`?